# iOS Background Execution and Preventing an App from being suspended/terminate

Tags: ios, core-location

I'm working on an internally-distributed iOS app (ie, no app store), and I'd like to be able to report back the location of the device at constant 10 minute intervals.

Anyway, I've included `location` as a key in the field `UIBackgroundModes` in my plist, hoping that would be sufficient to keep my app alive in the background while i ran a timer every time 10 minutes. However, I am discovering that, under some conditions, the app stops reporting these events. I suspect that the app is being moved in to a suspended state, perhaps then even getting terminated due to memory constraints. I've used instruments to analyze my memory footprint, and I've ruled out runaway memory allocation as a cause of termination.

How can i prevent the system from moving my app in to a suspended state? The docs say this about the location background mode:

> Enabling this mode does not prevent the system from suspending the
>   app, but it does tell the system that it should wake up the app
>   whenever there is new location data to deliver

Great. So it may be suspended, but new location data will re-awaken it. But what if there is no new location data? Can I prevent the App from EVER getting suspended? Perhaps using a different backgruond mode?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suppose you can use the audio playback background mode and start playing a silent media file once your app goes into background. According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24) this will prevent the app from being suspended. Not very appropriate for App Store submission, but since your app is deployed internally it might suit you

Comment: You can be terminated even when using very little memory. As the user launches more and more applications, as soon as there are more apps than RAM, some app will be terminated. There are some ways to identify yourself as a "good citizen" like releasing memory when you are asked to, which means you will live longer than "bad citizens", but eventually you'll be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things to prevent location manager from pausing, there are:

self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationsUpdates= true
self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

You also may need to add this:
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

Hope this helps,

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];

But this will drain your battery rapidly !